# SQLce 4.0 from enterprise library 5.0 ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have an MVC3 project in which I have to  select/update data from SQLCE database using enterprise library 5.0. For this I have to add reference to SQLCE dll.

If I reference the dll from SQLCE 4.0 , I get the error

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I can only guess that enterprise library 5.0 is specifically looking for sqlce 3.5 dll.

However if I reference the 3.5 dll in the project I get the error from ASP.NET that ASP.NET is not compatible with SQLCE .

I did search the internet but I cant find a solution yet.

can somebody give me some info please

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must recompile the Entrprise Library source, pointing it the the 4.0 ADO.NET Provider.